# Conditional pasting of values, making use of neighbouring cells

Tags: excel

I have a large data set with quite a bunch of missing data and I'm having some problems to paste values to specified cells. The core of the problem is well illustrated below:

Simplified illustration of problem can be found here:
[image: Simplified illustration of problem can be found here]

What I have tried is to make use of the IF statement to its neighbouring cell. But the condition should be set to a range of values not just one cel.

What I would like to find out: Is how to achieve this type of conditional pasting in an efficient way for a large dataset without doing it all by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done, using a combination of `VLOOKUP()` and `IFNA()`:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(E3;$A$3:$B$7;2;FALSE);"")
```

- `VLOOKUP()`: look for cell E3 in the fix range $A$3:$B$7

  From that range take the second column.

  In case the value E3 is not found, an error is shown #N/A
- `IFNA()`: in case of the error value, replace it by an empty string.

Don't forget to drag this formula from F3 to F10.